# How to setup a good defense from unwanted content

Tags: privacy, xiaomi

I have an android phone, xiaomi if it matters. I want to set-up a defense for my phone, so that:

I can't view pornography in any possible form. No websites, no games, and not even "soft pornography" - things like "dating simulators" or anything like that. Not only on the web browser, I also wantnot to be able to download from the playstore any app that contains content like that.

Block access to youtube or anyway to reach it.

Possibly (I'm still thinking about it) completely blocking access to a web browser.

I still want to be able to use everything else of course: navigation apps, bank apps, etc.

I want to do it for free if possible.

It is very hard, almost impossible, to remove the defense. So an app that i can delete any moment isn't going to do the job.

I searched the web for a good solution, but i'm quiet confused by all the information. If anyone knows how to setup such a defense that would be amazing.

Comment: You havent explained why, which is part of the question/solution.  Is it for a child or are you trying to protect yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Getting all of what you want may be quite hard. Your classification of apps doesn't seem to match Play Store categories, and those are not completely reliable in any case.

[Parental controls](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1075738?hl=en-GB) could be used, if you have someone who will organise them for you, but they won't block the results of searches, and they may not allow banking apps.

There is a market for "Kosher phones" which are used by some Hassidic Jews who see the Internet as a major danger to their culture, but feel that mobile telephony and GPS navigation are OK and useful. Those don't allow web browsing at all. The problems for you are that they don't allow installing apps, so you can't have your banking app, and they are quite expensive.